# how to tell homebrew to fetch a package from a certain url?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm installing `gfortran` via `brew`, which is trying to fetch a dependency called `mpfr` from http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.1/mpfr-3.1.1.tar.bz2 . However, the link seems to be dead. `brew` said `Recv failure`, I can not open it with my broswer either.

Then I found an alternative url to fetch it: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/mpfr/mpfr-3.1.1.tar.bz2 , I think they are just the same thing. How to tell `brew` to fetch it from the latter url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh I found it's pretty easy:

1. run `brew edit mpfr`.
2. replace the url.
3. comment out the `def patches` block.

Then try `brew install mpfr` again, it works fine.